# How to reuse Physical memory in the absence of swapping?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

How can I reuse physical memory in the absence of swapping?

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean by reuse? Writting dirty cache? Using sharing memory? Deallocating/reallocating physical space?

Comment: I think I am meant to say __De-allocating/reallocating physical space__.

Comment: Possibly [my answer from other question will be useful](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5336/how-is-paging-managed-in-the-absence-of-swapping/5362#5362). However please see [discussion if those questions are on-topic](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363/are-operating-system-questions-are-on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Just don't ? Let the kernel do its job, it knows better ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't... one the memory is allocated, other process can't reuse it because... well, it is use!

if you dont have swap (probably because there is no HD, want to avoid burning the ssd/SD card write cycles, etc), you can try to use the [zram](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zram).

This way you burn a little of ram to have a compressed swap that can save you lots of ram. It is available in kernel 3.11 and safe to use. Older kernels may have it in staging, but might still have some bugs.