# what could cause large pagefault latencies in linux?

Tags: linux, performance

I'm running a Linux netbook with an SSD. Since the SSD is slow (and I don't want to wear it out) I've been running without swap. So far this has been great, but I recently put a new kernel on (2.6.37) and noticed some slowdown. During this the disk drive light on my netbook stays on. LatencyTOP is only partially helpful in this, while one 3s (that's *seconds* not ms) delay is for 'disk write (synchronous),' one is 2s for 'page fault.' I don't understand why there would be much of a penalty for a page fault at all since I'm not using swap to begin with (and seem to have a lot of free/cached memory). What could be the cause of this, and is there a way to resolve it? Is such a high latency for page faults even harmful or is the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answers on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5336/how-is-paging-managed-in-the-absence-of-swapping) may help you out. Page faults occur even on the absence of swap, when the program tries to access a part of the virtual memory that is mapped but not yet on the physical memory like data from an on-disk file. The correct term for that technique is [Demand Paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging).